# MediaRecorder illegalstateexception the second time

Tags: java, android, exception, illegalstateexception

It's self explanatory. mediarecorder class's start method throws an illegalstateexception the second it's called. First time I press the button it all works fine. The second time it does not. I thread a lot of things and Idk what's wrong. I tried solutions from other questions regarding the media recorder but they didn't help. The permissions are place in the manifest. so that isn't the issue obviously since it works the first time.

MAIN

```
package com.boomer.omer.notetoself;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


public class Activity_Main extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

ProgressBar progressBar_record;
Button button_record;
Recorder recorder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    progressBar_record = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar_recorder);
    button_record = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_record);
    button_record.setOnTouchListener(this);
    recorder = null;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button_record:
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                button_record.setText("RECORDING");
                startRecorder();

            }else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                button_record.setText("RECORD");
                stopRecorder();
            }
            break;


    }



    return false;
}

public void startRecorder(){
    recorder = new Recorder(this,progressBar_record);
    recorder.execute();
}
public void stopRecorder(){
    progressBar_record.setProgress(0);
    recorder.cancel(true);
    recorder = null;

}



}
```

RECORDER CLASS

```
public class Recorder extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Void> {

public static final String LOG_TAG = "NTS:";
static final int MAX_LENGTH = 30;

MediaRecorder mRecorder;
String mFileName = null;

ProgressBar recordBar;
Activity parentActivity;

int mLength = 0;



public Recorder(Activity activity,ProgressBar progressBar) {
    super();
    mFileName = activity.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/recentRecord.3gp";

    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    recordBar = progressBar;
    parentActivity =activity;

}

public void startRecording(){

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }

    mRecorder.start();

}

public void stopRecording(){

    mRecorder.stop();
    mRecorder.reset();
    mRecorder.release();
    mRecorder = null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    startRecording();

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    long secondMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
   while(mLength < MAX_LENGTH){
       if((System.currentTimeMillis() - secondMillis) >= 1000){
           secondMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
           mLength++;
           publishProgress(mLength);



       }
   }

    stopRecording();
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    stopRecording();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    recordBar.setProgress(values[0]);



}

@Override
protected void onCancelled(Void aVoid) {
    super.onCancelled(aVoid);
    stopRecording();

}

@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    super.onCancelled();
    stopRecording();
}


 }
```

Comment: why are you calling stopRecording() method in doInBackground while you have called it in onPostExecute(). In the case of when recording finishes in doInBackground you just need to call stopRecording in onPostExecute() and remove call from doInBackground.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. I removed it and the result is the same